# Linux Mint not using full screen, menubar gone

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, cinnamon, desktop-environment, nemo

I seem to have entered some strange "mode" in Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon that I don't know how to exit. It persists between reboots.

This results in the following changes:

- The desktop is only usable in the upper left
- No keyboard shortcuts seem to work
- The menubar is gone
- Window top bars is gone
- A white box appears when typing outside a window
- A strange cursor

I can temporarily fix this with

```
cinnamon --replace
```

which gives the following output

> Cjs-Message: JS LOG: About to start Cinnamon
>   St-Message: cogl npot texture sizes SUPPORTED
>   Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Cinnamon started at Wed Sep 21 2016 12:28:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)
>   Cjs-Message: JS LOG: network applet: Cannot find connection for active (or connection cannot be read)
>   openGL version 3.3 detected (GL3 Cogl Driver)
>   MetaSyncRing disabled: couldn't find required GL extensions, or the minimum safe openGL version was not met
>   Cjs-Message: JS LOG: Invalid network device type, is 14
>   Cjs-Message: JS LOG: network applet: Found connection for active

and reverts if closed.

I think the problem happened when I had some problems with TeamViewer but I've tried uninstalling TeamViewer with `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all teamviewer:i386` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

**What is this "mode", and how do I fix it?**

[image][image]

*I couldn't get a good screenshot that fully shows the problem, so I took some photos instead.*